# Apache Solr 6.1.0 cores being deleted when solr restart

Tags: solr

i am running solr 6.1.0 on windows server 2008 R2. using windows command, i am able to start the solr also able to create core from the Admin GUI (http://localhost:8983/solr/#/), all working fine until i restart.

when restart using commnad window "D:\mydir\solr>bin\solr restart -p 8983"
then goback to browser http://localhost:8983/solr/#/ and refresh the core i have created are missing, But the Core Folders are exist in the solr home folder.

anybody know how to stop cores deleted?

Comment: Having the same issue. Tried both `solr cloud` and `standalone`. For the `standalone` configuration, I am able to run `solr`, create `core`, import data via `DIH`, and start making queries. Everything works fine until I re-start it. I am on Amazon Linux AMI, tried Solr 6.0.1, 6.3.0, 6.4.1. All failed to restart. And yes, I only have one core, and started solr from the same location `sudo service solr start`. After restart, I can not find any core in "Core Admin". But I can select my previous core in "Core Selector". Only that after selecting it, an error message "Connection to Solr lost" shows

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the first Solr start and the second used the same home? If you started the first time with `bin\solr start -e examplename` , then your home might be in a different location depending on the example chosen. Restarting Solr without example information uses the default **server** location.

Try starting solr with `bin\solr start -s path_to_home` and see if the cores are found then.

Answer (score 0):

Do You have multiple cores in your solr-Installation?

If yes, check the core.properties for duplicate "name"-Attribute.

Also check your solr log files for errors regarding CorePropertiesLocator.